# Nautilus error after upgrading from 12.10 to 13.04

Tags: nautilus

The desktop icons were missing. I installed the compizconfig-settings manager to restore the icons. I followed this steps:

- Press Ctrl+Alt+T to open a terminal window.
- At the terminal prompt, type `ccsm`.
- Type `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`.
- At the next terminal prompt, type `ccsm`.
- In CompizConfig Settings Manager, select the check box for the OpenGL plugin if it isn't already selected.
- Click the Ubuntu Unity Plugin item.
- Select the Enable Ubuntu Unity Plugin check box, if it isn't already selected. If it is already selected then uncheck this and again select it.
- Exit from the CompizConfig Settings Manager.

The icons are displayed again. Now I need to resolve another issue. When I try to open Nautilus (when enter code: `gksu nautilus`) I got the following message:

```
(nautilus:13161): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from `GtkMessageDialog' to `NautilusWindow'
**
ERROR:nautilus-window.c:1826:nautilus_window_get_slots: assertion failed: (NAUTILUS_IS_WINDOW (window))
```

Comment: Why do you need to run Nautilus as root?

Comment: I created six (6) users account. I created 7 folders (one per user and one public folder). I shared them, so they can access within the network. I want to run Nautilus to go to the Home folder to set permissions on share folders. I upgraded to 13.10, but there an error on Nautilus.

Comment: I got this

Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: info_fn: file /var/lib/samba/usershares/untitled folder is not a well formed usershare file.
info_fn: Error was Path is not a directory.
info_fn: file /var/lib/samba/usershares/assistant_folder is not a well formed usershare file.
info_fn: Error was Path is not a directory.
info_fn: file /var/lib/samba/usershares/adm. is not a well formed usershare file.
info_fn: Error was Path is not a directory.
info_fn: file /var/lib/samba/usershares/adm&rec is not a well formed usershare file.

Answer (score 0):

To change permissions on a folder, it may be simpler to use [`chmod`](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html):

```
sudo chmod -R 666 /PATH/TO/FOLDER
```

should work.

You may want to try another File Manager to Nautilus to see if that works better - [Nemo](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/nemo/) runs well with `gksu..`, and it also has:

[image]